# Transform Supercell to Unitcell

Tags: software, python, supercell

I’ve supercells of around 10,000 Metal–organic frameworks (MOF) structures in CIF format. I’m looking to convert them to unit cells. But I’m not able to find packages (or any other libraries like Pymatgen) doing this. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

## ASE

You could use ASE (Atomic Simulation Environment) to achieve this.
Here is a sample code.

I have tried the below code on three CIF files which can be found on the Crystallography Open Database here:
[1000017](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1000017.html),
[1000003](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1000003.html),
[1569089](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/1569089.html)

```
from ase.geometry.analysis import Analysis
import numpy as np
import os
from ase.io import read, write

# Path to the directory containing CIF files
cif_directory = "path/to/your/cif/files"

# Path to the directory where you want to save the unit cell CIF files
output_directory = "path/to/output/directory"


def find_unit_cell(supercell):
    # Calculate the inverse of the lattice transformation matrix
    inv_lattice = np.linalg.inv(supercell.cell.T)
    
    # Calculate the fractional positions in the supercell
    fractional_positions = np.dot(supercell.positions, inv_lattice)
    
    # Find unique fractional positions to determine unit cell
    unique_fractional_positions, indices = np.unique(fractional_positions, axis=0, return_index=True)
    
    # Create the unit cell by selecting atoms at unique fractional positions
    unit_cell = supercell[indices]
    
    return unit_cell

# Loop through all CIF files in the directory
for cif_filename in os.listdir(cif_directory):
    print(cif_filename)
    if cif_filename.endswith(".cif"):
        cif_path = os.path.join(cif_directory, cif_filename)
        supercell = read(cif_path)
        

        # Convert supercell to unit cell
        unit_cell = find_unit_cell(supercell)
        
        # Save the unit cell CIF
        output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, cif_filename)
        write(output_path, unit_cell, format="cif")
        
        print(f"Converted {cif_filename} to unit cell and saved to {output_path}")
```

Comment: Thanks Vandan! I think I'm not exactly following your script. I tried to understand using following code: 

        pri_cell = bulk('Au') \\
        M = [[2, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 2]] \\
        supercell = make_supercell(pri_cell, M) \\
        unit_cell = find_unit_cell(supercell) \\

I expected unit_cell to be similar to pri_cell, but unit_cell created seem to be the supercell itself. Can you please let me know how you tested using the three CIFs from  Crystallography Open Database? and possibly your thoughts on what's going wrong here?